# Using separate functions based on template class type

Tags: c++, hash, hashtable

I have a fairly simple assignment to review hash tables, and we have to create a template class and test it using floats, ints, and STL strings as key data types.

I have the class setup like so:

```
 template<class K, class T>
 class hashTable{
     public:
     private:
 };
```

When I call the class to test it, I use:

```
hashTable<float, data>
hashTable<int, data>
```

etc... I just am not sure how to make the class use the hash function I have for each data type based on what data type I use when I call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least three approaches:

First. Create an overloaded function `hash` for all your types:

```
hash_t hash(int);
hash_t hash(float);
```

and in `hashTable` just call `hash()`.

Second. Create a separate templated class (or, well, a function) `hash<T>` and specialize it for `int`, `float`, etc. Then in `hastTable` refer to it in general way as `hash<K>`:

```
 template<class T> class hash;
 template<> class hash<int> { hash_t operator() {...} };
 template<> class hash<float> { hash_t operator() {...} };
```

Third. Supply the needed class or function via a template parameter to `hashTable`, just the way the standard `std::sort` received comparison function:

```
template<class K, class T, class Hash>
class hashTable...
```

Comment: I don't know how I forgot about overloaded functions, it worked perfectly. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do it like the standard does.  Add a template parameter for the hash function and then use the standard hash.  If you have a custom type that the standard hash does not work for then you can implement you own and include it in the template arguments.

```
template<class K, class T, class Hash = std::hash<K>>
class hashTable{ 
// stuff 
};
```